# Getting absolute path of image from mysql php from relative path which is stored

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am fetching data from mysql as json encode.  Everything works fine except the image path, which is not an absolute path in database - it's just a relative path such as `images/starwars.jpg`. I am developing a mobile app and want the absolute path to get the image displayed.

It should display like `http://sample.com/images/starwars.jpg`.

It can be done by changing the name path in DB but I am looking for an alternate solution.

The field to get the image path I am using is: `$row['path']=$row['path'];`

The php code is to encode json object is:

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(movie.filmReleaseDate,'%d %b %Y')filmReleaseDate, movie.filmName, movie.filmDirector, movie.url, images.path FROM movie INNER JOIN images ON movie.filmId = images.filmId WHERE movie.filmReleaseDate >= NOW() GROUP by images.filmId ORDER BY DATE(films.filmReleaseDate) LIMIT 0 , 12";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$json = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))//loop through the retrieved values
{
        $row['filmName']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['filmName']));      
        $row['filmDirector']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['filmDirector']));
        $row['filmReleaseDate']=$row['filmReleaseDate'];
        $row['url']=$row['url'];
        $row['path']=$row['path'];

        $json[] = $row;//build an array
}
echo json_encode(array('upcomingFilms' => $json));

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use CONCAT in query request.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

```
SELECT ... CONCAT('http://sample.com/images/', images.path) ...
```

Comment: Great answer... thanks a lot "CONCAT('http://sample.com/images/', images.path) AS path" worked perfectly